# asp.net vb Button.click insert to sql working at client but not working when move to server

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, insert

This code is working a PC. I have filled grid view with the dataset, so I suppose I can read Excel.

However, the `insert to sql` part is not working when I copy the code to the server and I don't know why. It is not throwing any errors.

I removed the `try catch` lines but still, there are no errors.

I am adding new code block, I did a test and wrote a siple `insert code`  like;

```vb
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim mysql_connection As New SqlConnection

        mysql_connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SRV01;Initial Catalog=TR_Development;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa"

        Dim command As String = "insert into gez_test (test) values ('c')"

        Dim mysqlcommand As New SqlCommand

        mysqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        mysqlcommand.CommandText = command
        mysqlcommand.Connection = mysql_connection

        If mysql_connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then mysql_connection.Open()

        mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If mysql_connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then mysql_connection.Close()


    End Sub
```

And at server it is not inserting. What can be the problem any idea?

**Orginal code**

```vb
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
Button1.Click

    Dim path_ As String = "\\exchange\COMPANY\web\" + FileUpload1.FileName

    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path_)

    Dim identifier As Boolean = False
    Dim connStr As String = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + path_ + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
    Dim MyConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim MyCommand As OleDbDataAdapter

    MyConnection = New OleDbConnection(connStr)

    MyConnection.Open()

    Dim dtSheets As DataTable = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    Dim listSheet As New List(Of String)
    Dim drSheet As DataRow

    For Each drSheet In dtSheets.Rows
        listSheet.Add(drSheet("TABLE_NAME").ToString())
    Next

    For Each sheet As String In listSheet

        If sheet = "'BAS+Surcharges$'" Then
            identifier = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If identifier = True Then
        MyCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [BAS+Surcharges$]", MyConnection)

        ds = New System.Data.DataSet()

        MyCommand.Fill(ds)
        MyConnection.Close()

        '**************SQL***************

        Dim line, columns As Integer

        line = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

        columns = ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count

        Label1.Text = line.ToString
        ASPxTextBox1.Text = line.ToString

        If line > 0 And columns = 16 Then

            Dim command As String = "exec SP_INTRA_EXCEL_LINE_INSERT" _
                                    + " @line_isim, @nereden, @via, @nereye, @transit_sure, @baslangic_tarihi," _
                                    + "@e_kadar_gecerli, @kalem_kodu, @fiyatlandirma, @20DRY, @40DRY, @40HDRY," _
                                    + "@40HREF_NOR, @kayit_eden"

            Dim mysql_connection As New SqlConnection
            mysql_connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TR_DevelopmentConnectionString").ConnectionString

            Dim mysqlcommand As New SqlCommand
            mysqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            mysqlcommand.CommandText = command
            mysqlcommand.Connection = mysql_connection

            Dim line_isim, nereden, via, nereye, transit_sure, baslangic_tarihi, e_kadar_gecerli,
            kalem_kodu, fiyatlandirma, _20DRY, _40DRY, _40HDRY,
            _40HREF_NOR, kayit_eden As String

            If mysql_connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then mysql_connection.Open()

            For i = 6 To line - 1

                line_isim = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(13).ToString
                nereden = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
                via = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(14).ToString
                nereye = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
                transit_sure = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(15).ToString
                baslangic_tarihi = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).ToString).ToString
                e_kadar_gecerli = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3).ToString).ToString
                kalem_kodu = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(7).ToString
                fiyatlandirma = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(8).ToString
                _20DRY = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(9).ToString
                _40DRY = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(10).ToString
                _40HDRY = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(11).ToString
                _40HREF_NOR = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(12).ToString
                kayit_eden = Environment.UserName.ToString

                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line_isim", line_isim)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nereden", nereden)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@via", via)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nereye", nereye)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transit_sure", transit_sure)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baslangic_tarihi", baslangic_tarihi)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_kadar_gecerli", e_kadar_gecerli)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kalem_kodu", kalem_kodu)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fiyatlandirma", fiyatlandirma)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@20DRY", _20DRY)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@40DRY", _40DRY)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@40HDRY", _40HDRY)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@40HREF_NOR", _40HREF_NOR)
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kayit_eden", kayit_eden)
                mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                mysqlcommand.Parameters.Clear()
            Next

            If mysql_connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then mysql_connection.Close()
        End If
    End If

    ASPxGridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thanks for editing, I will be more careful.

Comment: If either of these evaluate to false, you will fail with no exception or even message: `If identifier = True Then` and `If line > 0 And columns = 16 Then`. The first one depends on finding the file. A number of things could go wrong when trying to open the file. Does the other PC have access to it? Has it been uploaded? Is the filename empty? You should make cases for when things fail (try...catch actually works well) and alert the user somehow. This can help you debug your code.

Comment: Also, please just provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we need to scroll your code example to see the big picture, it is probably too big.

Comment: Brake your code into smaller methods

Comment: Thanks for answers, in code i used to fill gridview directly with dataset. It is working. Also server has access and file is not empty. When i add sql block, its not working and not inserting to sql. IIS and sql server are on same pc.

Comment: @Verdolino I did a test, and added a siple `insert code`.  I edited the post, if you can share your comment i will be glad thant you.